# Pi Glow programming

Tags: python

After following the steps on this page https://github.com/Boeeerb/PiGlow. I did everything correctly and when i try to run the test.py file it says this.

Traceback (most recent call last) :
   File "test.py" , line 9, in 
      piglow = PiGlow()
    File "/home/pi/piglow/piglow.py" , line 30,in *init*
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have tried rebooting, and trying it multiple times. I pressed ls and it was there.I dont have twitter so please dont comment about that

Answer (score 0):

i2c modules has been loaded ? try to run "lsmod | grep i2c", to check if modules are loaded. Also, is very important you run test program as root.